# Data format for LIBSVM

Tags: machine-learning, libsvm

I need to know how the data format will be prepared  for the following example in LIBSVM

I have two classes as sports and politics

In sports category i have two documents with content as follows

Doc1: Soccer world cup 2014
Doc2: Ronaldo is the best soccer player

In politics category have three documents with content as follows

Doc1: politics is very bad
Doc2: Stay away from politics
Doc3: politicians are game players

Now from the above 6 documents of 2 categories i want to know how will the training file of LIBSVM can be prepared ?

and also one more question can i prepare two LIBSVM training files for each category and use in LIBSVM.Net.
If yes then how can i use two training files and use them?

Answer (score 1):

Seems you are mixing two different questions:

1. How to represent documents as feature vectors which can be fed to a classifier
2. How to use specific library, such as LIBSVM or LIMSVM.NET (I am not sure what the 2nd is, did you mean [this](https://code.google.com/p/libsvm-net/)? You should be more specific).

Regarding the 1st question, there are quite a few possibilities, depending on the task. A possible simple approach is the [tf-idf representation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tf%E2%80%93idf).

Regarding using the libraries, what did you try, and what didn't work? Did you read the documentation? LIBSVM has quite an informative and clear [guide](http://www.csie.ntu.edu.tw/~cjlin/papers/guide/guide.pdf).

Comment: For 1 question can you show me how the training data will be prepared like not with coding but a sample output file like 1 1:2 2:4 etc for all documents in two categories because thats what am confused of and for 2nd question can i use like in this link at the end http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6172159/how-to-use-libsvm-for-text-classification int libsvm.net?